# Analyzing message ios app

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, nsmutablearray

I analyze my app And I am getting this message :

**value stored in object during its intialization is never used.**

Here is my code:

```
{
        dataArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        dataArray=root[@"data"];
        NSMutableDictionary *object=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]; //Here I am getting that message
        searchedName=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for(int i=0;i<[dataArray count];i++)
       {
            object=[dataArray objectAtIndex:i];
            [searchedName addObject:object[@"charityName"]];
        }
    }
```

I don't know what it is trying to say. Can any one help me?

Comment: You can't use the variable name `object` its a reserved keyword of iOS, try some other name like `dictionary`, or `dicObject`, it should work

Comment: @iphonic though  it is working without any error....

Comment: you are getting error at this line `NSMutableDictionary *object=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];` which contains `object`

Comment: I am not getting any error I just got message at that line when I analyzed my code...otherwise it is working fine with that line also

Answer (score 2):

It's trying to say that you never use `[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]` value which you initialise your `object` variable with. First you make your `object` point to new empty dictionary, created with `[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]` but then you make it point to every object in `dataArray`

Actually you don't need these two lines:

```
dataArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

and:

```
NSMutableDictionary *object=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
```

The second one should be `NSMutableDictionary *object = nil;` instead

Answer (score 0):

remove `dataArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];` line its unnecessary and replace `NSMutableDictionary *object=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];` with `NSDictionary *object=nil;`

```
{
    dataArray=root[@"data"];
    NSDictionary *object=nil; //Here I am getting that message
    searchedName=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(int i=0;i<[dataArray count];i++){
        object=[dataArray objectAtIndex:i];
        [searchedName addObject:object[@"charityName"]];
    }
}
```